# Name error uninititalized constant when storing controller inside subfolder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, namespaces

The JSON API I am building has a set of routes under the namespace API and V1 (all the routes start with API/V1. 
I am now creating a new set of controllers and models that are all linked to the "concept" of "association" so I decided to store them in a subfolder "association" inside my folders "controllers" and "models". I also created a new namespace "association" for the routes relative to these controllers.

I have been trying to POST on the create action of the OfficesController but I am getting this :

```
Started POST "/api/v1/association/account_assos/1/offices" for ::1 at 2016-04-26 13:54:00 +0200
Processing by Api::V1::Association::OfficesController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"office"=>{"name"=>"Samu Paris", "contact_mail"=>"samuparis@gmail.com", "contact_phone"=>"+33666027414", "address"=>"148 BD BINEAU", "city"=>"PARIS", "postcode"=>"92200", "photos_attributes"=>[{"image_url"=>""}]}, "account_asso_id"=>"1"}
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["email", "mariashi@gmail.com"]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 50ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)

**NameError - uninitialized constant Api::V1::Association::OfficesController::Association:**
```

My routes look like :

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
      namespace :v1 do
        namespace :association do
          resources :account_assos, only: [ :index, :show, :update, :create ] do
            resources :offices, only: [ :index, :show, :create ]
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

And the problematic controller :

```
class Api::V1::Association::OfficesController < Api::V1::BaseController
  before_action :set_office, only: [ :show, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_account_asso, only: [:create, :index]


  def index
    # is this the best way ??
    if (current_user.created_account_asso == @account_asso) || ((current_user.account_asso == @account_asso) && (current_user.status == "manager"))
      @offices = policy_scope(office).where(account_asso: @account_asso)
      render :index
    else
      render json: {message: "Unauthorized"}
    end
  end

  def show
    authorize @office
  end

  def update
    authorize @office
    if @Office.update(office_params)
      render :show
    else
      render_error
    end
  end

  # input account
  def create
    @office = @account_asso.offices.build(office_params)
    authorize @office
    if @office.save
      render :show
    else
      render_error
    end
  end

  def destroy
    authorize @office
    if @office.destroy
      render json: {success: "Office successfully destroyed"}
    else
      render json: {error: "There was an error please try again"}
    end
  end

  private

  def set_account_asso
    @account_asso = Association::AccountAsso.find(params[:account_asso_id])
  end

  def set_office
    @office = Office.find(params[:id])
  end

  def Office_params
    params.require(:office).permit( :name,
                                    :address,
                                    :contact_mail,
                                    :contact_phone,
                                    :address,
                                    :city,
                                    :postcode,
                                    photos_attributes: [ :image_url ]
                                  )
  end

  def render_error
    render json: { errors: @office.errors.full_messages }, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end

end
```

The `offices_controller` is stored in api/v1/association which seems consistent to me. Why am I then getting

```
  **NameError - uninitialized constant Api::V1::Association::OfficesController::Association:**
```

My models relative to the "association" concept are stored in models/association. This is my AccountAsso model for example (models/association/account_asso.rb) :

```
class Association::AccountAsso < ActiveRecord::Base

  # associations
  has_many :users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :offices, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :admin, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "admin_user_id"


  # validations

  validates :name, presence: true, length: {minimum: 2}
  validates_format_of :contact_mail,:with => Devise::email_regexp
  validates :contact_tel, format: {
      with:     /\A(\+33)[1-9]([-. ]?[0-9]{2}){4}\z/,
      message:  'Le format de votre numéro doit être du type +33602385414'
    }
  validates :iban, presence: true, format: {
      with:     /\A[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{2}\s*(\w{4}\s*){2,7}\w{1,4}\s*\z/,
      message:  'Le format de votre IBAN doit être du type FR70 3000 2005 5000 0015 7845 Z02'
    }, allow_blank: true

  validates :bic, presence: true, format: {
      with:     /([a-zA-Z]{4}[a-zA-Z]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})?)/,
      message:  'Le format de votre BIC doit être du type AXABFRPP  '
    }, allow_blank: true

  validates :admin, presence: true, uniqueness: true


  # validates :legal_status, presence: true,

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since on that path controller can't find parent constant `Association`, use full path to `Api::V1::Association`, or relative one class method `::parent`:

```
@account_asso = Api::V1::Association::AccountAsso.find(params[:account_asso_id])
```

or

```
@account_asso = parent::AccountAsso.find(params[:account_asso_id])
```

Well, since `AccountAsso` is a model, its declaration should accounted from a namespace root, because they are not a part of the rails serving subsystem etc. Of course you can have submodels, but they should belong to the parent model and not one other, so:

**app/models/account_asso.rb**

```
class AccountAsso < ActiveRecord::Base ;end
```

and with submodel:

**app/models/account_asso/new_asso.rb**

```
class AccountAsso::NewAsso < AccountAsso ;end
```

or:

**app/models/account_asso/otherm.rb**

```
class AccountAsso::Otherm < ActiveRecord::Base ;end
```

NOTE: The models name **must** correnspond path to the model file, otherwise rails can't pick up it properly.

Comment: this gives me NameError - uninitialized constant Api::V1::Association::OfficesController::Association: because in my models folder the AccountAsso model is at this path models/association/account_asso.rb. Are you suggesting I should store it at this path  models/api/v1/association/account_asso.rb ?

Comment: @Dave where and how did you defined the model? model decalration should accounted from a root, because they are not a part of a controller subsystem etc.

Comment: i will complete my post

Answer (score -1):

```
Started POST "/api/v1/association/account_assos/1/offices" for ::1 at 2016-04-26 13:54:00 +0200
Processing by Api::V1::Association::OfficesController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"office"=>{"name"=>"Samu Paris", "contact_mail"=>"samuparis@gmail.com", "contact_phone"=>"+33666027414", "address"=>"148 BD BINEAU", "city"=>"PARIS", "postcode"=>"92200", "photos_attributes"=>[{"image_url"=>""}]}, "account_asso_id"=>"1"}
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["email", "mariashi@gmail.com"]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 50ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)

**NameError - uninitialized constant Api::V1::Association::OfficesController::Association:**
```

Look at the URL, It has the wrong name as well, Instead of offices you are calling offices.

Comment: sorry I dont get your answer. I think this is the correct url to the create action of the offices_controller...

Answer (score -1):

Did you restart the server? Moreover, your `association` folder should be at the following path: `app/controllers/api/v1/association/`

Comment: Hey, I did restart my server and my association folder is exactly there